# Python creating a readonly wrapper class without modifying wrapped class

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, wrapper, setattr

I have a base class that looks like follows:

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self, prop):
        self.prop = prop
```

I want to create a wrapper class `ReadonlyWrapper` that is read-only, with the following functionality:

```
# Create instance using __init__ of base class.
readonly_instance = ReadonlyWrapper()

# I can access properties
prop = readonly_instance.prop

# This should raise a PermissionError
readonly_instance.prop = 23
```

More precisely I want that all field of the class are read-only, but only after `__init__` is called, otherwise the class cannot be constructed in the constructor itself.
I know it can be done using the property decorator, but I do not want to turn all attributes into properties.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by overriding `__setattr__` in the following way:

```
class ReadonlyWrapper(Base):
    _initialized = False

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ReadonlyWrapper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._initialized = True

    def __setattr__(self, key, value) -> None:
        if self._initialized:
            raise PermissionError()
        else:
            super().__setattr__(key, value)
```

Once `_initialized` is set to `True`, any attempt to set an attribute will raise a `PermissionError`.